# Restrict user from inputting certain languages.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website which include a comment area for users. Example a guestbook or a product review. And I want to restrict a user on posting inappropriate languages on the comment area. For example: vulgarities.

If the user input any vulgarities, the characters would be replace by * . *Example - from stupid to s * * * * **.

I had been researching on related website but it was unfruitful. Suggestions or tutorials on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: g00Δ lück 1n ¥our €ff0rt

Comment: Hire a fulltime moderator. I doubt there are better solutions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way to fully stop "bad language" from being used but you can try to prevent it by creating a text file that contains a bad word in every line. Then load the list of words from the file to a `List<String>` in your program. You can do so by doing the following:

```
// The list of swear words
List<string> swearWords = new List<string>();

private void GetSwearWords()
{
    // Get the path to the file that has the swear words list
    string path = <File Path>;

    // Open the text file
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    // Loop through each line in the file.
    string line = "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       // Lower cases word and removes whitespaces
       string word = line.Trim().ToLower();

       // Adds the word to the list
       swearWords.Add(word);
    }
}
```

Then, to determine if a string has one of these bad words you do the following:

```
private bool HasSwearWord(string text)
{
    // Splits words, removes whitespace and any punctuation
    string[] wordArray = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+");

    // Check if any word in the string is a swear word
    foreach (string word in wordArray)
    {
        if (swearWords.Contains(word.ToLower()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Splitting a string is an expensive operation in .NET (as strings are immutable). I would iterate over each forbidden word and do `contentText.IndexOf(forbiddenWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureCaseInsensitive) > -1` instead.

Comment: That's a good idea. Of course, if you were to use IndexOf, then you have to remember to do contentText.Trim() beforehand, otherwise bad language with involves two words would not be detected.

Comment: But the strings in the List<String> have been trimmed so that if the person tries to fool the program by connecting the two words together, the program can still detect it.

Comment: @ArashAbiri try to filter `¥0u mōŤher fÚcker 1d1oŧ`